# Elasticbeanstalk process.env variables not set

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a Node v12 (5.2.2 platform) elastic beanstalk app, and set the env vars in the EB console.

Locally, I use `dotenv` to load envs, but EB does it their own way. The env variables are recognized when I view the elastic beanstalk server logs, but when I `ssh` into the EC2 instance, and `console.log(process.env)`, or `echo $MY_ENV_VAR`, none of the values are set.

So, I `source`'d the env vars at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` and can now `echo` them, but running migrations shows that the env vars are still unset, and `console.log(process.env)` shows none of them are set.

Why is this? How do I ensure they're set so I can run migrations and other commands that require envs?

---

`/root/.ebextensions/environmentvar.config`:

```
option_settings:
     aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
       TEST_VAR: helloworld
```

Comment: In your ebextentions, export the variables before you need them.

Comment: @Marcin isn't this handled when you set them in the eb console?

Comment: Maybe not at the stage you need them. Thus you can explicitly export them before hand `export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)`.

Comment: @Marcin where does that export function go?

Comment: You haven't provided reletance ebextention config file with your command for migration. If you provide it, it will be easier to add it.

Comment: @Marcin added above

Comment: I mean example of "run migrations and other commands that require envs"? which commands?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223223/discussion-between-growler-and-marcin).